# EF Code First, Unique Contraints, and Testing

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-5, code-first, unique-constraint

We currently are implementing our Unique constraint by executing SQL directly in the Seed method

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "BEGIN TRY ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT UC_CODE UNIQUE (COL1, COL2, COL3) END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH");
```

However, now I can't write tests properly for this.

I mock the Repository, and insert the same record twice, but...of course, no error is thrown, because the database isn't actually called (and it shouldn't be), but then how do I write a test that ensures an error is thrown when a duplicate record is inserted?

Comment: why not point your test at a test database?

Comment: @cameronjchurch, because that's slow, and hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit test needs to tun the code that you want to test. You want to test the EF+DB reaction to the constraint violations.  So, you need to run the tests on the real (test) database, that you can create in the beginning of the test.

Answer (score 0):

> I mock the Repository, and insert the same record twice, but...of
>   course, no error is thrown, because the database isn't actually called
>   (and it shouldn't be), but then how do I write a test that ensures an
>   error is thrown when a duplicate record is inserted?

You have misunderstood point of mocking and faking dependencies. Faked repository should not do any logic. If you test how will your code react on unique constraint violation you will simply set up your mock to throw the expected exception.

Comment: I'm not trying to test how I react to it, I'm trying to test that it happens when it should.

Comment: In such case you cannot mock it - you must test it against the real database because it is the source of the logic.

Comment: So what's the best way to do this, I don't want to use the REAL db, I'd like to spin up something and use EF to create a db specific for testing.  That gets removed when the tests are done.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expectations. If you want to use and test EF you need a database. It can be a database dedicated for testing and you can either use it whole time (and for example run each test in transaction which will rollback when the test is complete) or you can use EF to Create/Drop database for each test (but it will be slow).